# Macos: Applescript in Automator stopped working after 15.5.1 update

Tags: macos

This simple script suddenly stopped working on my MBP Monterey 15.5.1.
However it still works in my mac mini Monterey 15.5 and my MBP Catalina.
The script refuses to Change Directory (cd) no matter what I try.
The result being the "npm run start" command is presented to the normal command line not the MagicMirror directory.
Thanks for any help/advice.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set shell to do script "cd MagicMirror"
    delay 1
    do script "npm run start" in shell
end tell

enter code here
```

[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgyOJ.png)
[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzudR.png)

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Solved,
In case anyone else comes across this problem.
I had a Command Line util installed, autocomplete Fig.app, which conflicted with Monterey 15.5.1.
Uninstalled Fig all good, reinstalled broken again.